# Combine data in 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Example of initial data:

```
 Project   |   Modified   | LastModify |
 ---------------------------------------
 Project 1 |  12.01.2018  |      3     |
 Project 2 |  10.02.2017  |      2     |
 Project 1 |  15.01.2018  |      2     |
 Project 1 |  18.01.2018  |      1     |
 Project 2 |  15.02.2017  |      1     |
```

I have this result by query:

```
SELECT *
, Row_number() over (partition by Project order by Modified desc ) as LastModify
FROM Table_A
```

I need to add column with first modify project date for rows where column `Lastmodify = 1`

i.e. to get 1 row for each `Project` with first modified date and last modified date

Expected result looks like:

```
 Project   |   Modified   | LastModify | FirstModifyDate|
 ----------------------------------------------------
 Project 1 |  18.01.2018  |      1     |  12.01.2018   |
 Project 2 |  15.02.2017  |      1     |  10.02.2017   |
```

How I can do it?

Comment: sql server version?

Comment: 2017, sorry, I didn't add version to the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF your Sql server version is equal or higher than 2012, this will work:

```
SELECT *
, Row_number() over (partition by Project order by Modified desc ) as LastModify
, First_value(Modified) over (partition by Project order by Modified asc) [FirstModifyDate]
FROM Table_A
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a table like your data and apply the query it might help. [you can refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhwdG.png)

```
SELECT new.project
    ,new.times
    ,new.pdate
    ,sec.p1date
FROM new
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT child.project AS p
        ,child.pdate AS p1date
    FROM new AS child
    INNER JOIN new ON child.project = new.project
    GROUP BY child.project
    HAVING child.times = MAX(child.times)
    ) AS sec ON sec.p = new.project
WHERE new.times = 1
```